# Survfit function for gbm cox model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I just fitted a boosted regression coxph model:

```
cox=gbm(Surv(periods, event) ~ grade + fico_range_low + revol_util + dti, data=notes)
```

However, I want to obtain the survival curve from the model similar to the `survfit()` function in the `survival` package.  Does anyone know how to obtain using the model from the `gbm` package?

Comment: What made you choose to do boosting?  You don't have many variables so ordinary maximum likelihood estimation is likely to work fine.

Comment: I actually have many variables, i just put a few here to show a sample.  I am a newbie, so my thought regarding gbm is what I think is its ability to handle missing values without imputation.  I am worried about imputation bias as my data has many predictors with NAs.  Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: It depends on the method gbm uses for imputation.  What does it do?  And note that multiple imputation with many `NA`s and using ordinary modeling does not necessarily create a bias.

Comment: Thank you.  I have looked into multiple imputation.  However, I can t seem to figure out how to impute on new data.  It seems that the packages just impute a single data set. I am looking for a way to impute a training set and use the same imputation on test data.  Any suggestions?

Comment: By "impute on new data" I assume you mean "obtain predictions on new incomplete data".  That would seem to be a problem for both approaches, and learning how gbm does multiple imputation.

Comment: Yes, I will have new incomplete data that is a small subset of the training and test sets.  I would like to impute each set in the same way and then make prediction on this imputed data.  So, you are saying this is not an option for multiple imputation?  In regards to gradient boosting machine trees, I was under the impression that this type of model inherently handles missing values and does not need imputation.  That is, the trees are able to model observations with NAs.

Comment: I'm a bit dubious of the imputation ability of gbm but will be open to learning more.  Multiple imputation can be used for prediction - you multiply impute the predicted values, take the average, but look at the distribution because its width tells you the cost of not having the measurements.  One technical difficulty is that you have to temporarily remove the outcome variable when imputing predictors (multiple imputation requires the use of $Y$ to impute $X$, otherwise final coefficients in predicting $Y$ will be too small.  I suspect that gbm has this bias because of its imputation method).

Answer (score 1):

Since package `gbm` requires package `survival` and can use the `Surv()` function in the canonical formula interface, and there is also a reference to `survfit()` in the `basehaz.gbm()` documentation in the [gbm vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf), it might be possible to pull out what you're looking for using the gbm model object. I doubt it, though, based on what I've read so far.

So you might have to go to the source code and make your own function to extract or reconstruct what you need to mimic `plot(survfit())`. See also the (hidden) helper function `reconstructGBMdata()`.

I also wanted to comment on using gradient boosting models, specifically for handling missing values. The short answer here is that the gbm algorithm handles missing values explicitly, obviating the need for user-handled imputation. I suggest looking up package [rpart](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf) if you want to understand the technical details better.